# Styling MVC3 Validation Messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate

I love the default validation messages in MVC3 but now I am moving onto some much larger forms the form elements need to sit a lot tighter together. This causes issues with the default validation messages produced. They either wrap, leading to half the message appearing under the form element, or break my form layout completely.

Does anyone have a good solution to this problem?

Would setting the validation message to being a 'tooltip' help do you think? Would love to hear your suggestions and solutions.

Regards Paul

Comment: I think we would need to see more info about your layout to answer this. There are tons of ways to style validation messages. However, wrapping is a normal behavior. Do you have your validation inline with the form elements? Have you considered giving them their own column space, to the right of the form elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default validation message is a `SPAN`. If you want to use a different element (e.g. `IMG`),  you would need to create a custom validation message extension. Check out `ValidationMessageHelper` method in MVC to get an idea how the default `SPAN` is built. I think you can reuse the custom attributes like `data-valmsg-for`. Also, you need to modify the *jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js* assuming you are using unobtrusive ajax validation.

Answer (score 1):

This is all dependant upon your layout.  You can put the ValidationMessage anywhere you want, and style it any way you want.  Just look at the output HTML and figure out how to lay out the message how you want it.